# Strange behavior when defining long long variable in C

Tags: c

I have noticed a very strange behavior when I try to define variable that has type long long int.

For example, code written this way works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_LEN 20

int main()
{  
    long long broj = 1;

    char str[STR_LEN];
    scanf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

But, code written this way cannot be compiled:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_LEN 20

int main()
{  
    char str[STR_LEN];
    scanf("%s", str);

    long long broj = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler provides following message:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
which is not very helpful... I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Any thoughts about this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Compiles with gcc-4.8

Comment: Change the setting to compile it as C++. VC++ C support is archaic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any thoughts about this behavior?

Yes. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support the mix type declaration. Compile your code with GCC in C99 mode (use option `-std=c99`) and it will work fine. ISO C99 and ISO C++ allow declarations and code to be freely mixed within compound statements.
As an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Mixed-Declarations.html), GCC also allows this in C89 mode

Comment: Yes, I tried compiling it with GCC compiler and it works fine in both C89 and C99 mode. Thanks, this is probably the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010(C89),always initialize variables at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

1. `long` is a qualifier not a type, you are not explicitly declaring a type at all
2. historically, Windows/Visual Studio doesn't offer good support for C
3. you are not mentioning the options that you are using to compile this